# Command Line Web Deployment | Dotnet 6 | IIS | Jenkins | Command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

**What I am trying to achieve:** Deploy my dotnet application to the IIS server by Jenkins build machine.

**Error**:

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
> ("xx.xx.xxx.x") using the Web Management Service, but could not
> authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name an d
> password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
> credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.

**Background**: I have a dotnet solution with 5 projects[Main project, Test project, Test simulator, Seperate project for shared objects among services and a customised thirdparty library]. I use Jenkins freestyle task to build and deploy the project and it gives the above error message. Furthermore, I have another dotnet solution with 1 project and it is deployed by jenkins without any issue as it has only single project.

**Problem**

I can successfully publish a single project manually by visual studio (right click on the project -> click on "Publish" button -> click publish button) but I can not deploy solution even a single project by command line arguments

**Steps(command line):**

1. Initially I was trying to deploy the solution using the following command but I found that it is not possible as I have multiple projects according to  [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment).

   ```
   msbuild project_name.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="staging"
   ```
2. Then I updated other projects by adding publish profiles same as main projects publish profile name according to [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)]. I got the same error message.
3. Then I tried to deploy only the main project by following command but got the same error.

   ```
   msbuild path_to_project\projectname.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=staging /p:VisualStudioVersion=22.0 /p:Password="mypassword" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true
   ```

Is it possible to help me to find where the issue is and how to fix it ?

bellow I have mentioned the publish profile I used.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://myurl:80/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>projectguid</ProjectGuid>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8172/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>appName</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
    <UserName>xx.xx.xxx.xx\Administrator</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```